# How much power can i draw from Arduino Mega 2560's 3.3v pin?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, power

down vote
favorite
I am using external power supply (which is 12v 2 ampere power adapter) to power my arduino.
I have following components connect to 3.3v -

ESP-01
Sharp GP2Y1010AU0F
AMS iAQ-Core and
DHT22

Max current draw for each component is -

ESP-01 -> 170mA
SHARP GP2Y1010AU0F -> 20mA
AMS iAQ-Core C -> 20mA
DHT22 -> 2.5mA

Can Arduino Mega 2560 provide enough power for all the components?

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you cut and pasted it from your posting on Arduino stack exchange and cross posting is prohibited.  https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/38869/how-much-power-can-i-draw-from-arduino-mega-2560s-3-3v-pin

Comment: I dont know how much "power" an arduino can put out, but I dont recommend in general using microprocessing devices to "drive" power hungry machines.  Use the arduino to turn on or off a switching device that provides its own power to the load.

Answer (score 2):

No,  the small 3.3V linear regulator, which has no heatsink, can not do more than about 50mA or so.

Especially for the esp. Get a 3.3V switching/buck regulator that can do 500mA.

Answer (score 1):

If you Googled it, you wouldn't even have to click the first link to find out....
[image]

Passerby correctly pointed out that the URL describes the Mega 1280. The rating is the same, as you can confirm in [Arduino Mega 2560s page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/arduinoBoardMega2560).

The point stands though, both are very easy to find if you just looked for it.

Comment: That arduino is not the Mega 2560. It is the 1280 board.

Comment: @Passerby -- yeah, but its the same rating as the 2560: https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/arduinoBoardMega2560

Comment: I know that,  but your attempt to tell someone lmgtfy fails when you don't look at your own screenshot.

Comment: @Passerby -- I incorrectly assumed all products with the name "Arduino Mega" were the same - since there are no official UNOs with Atmega168, etc. My mistake.